# how to forward 80 port to domain using nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, iptables

i used centos 7 nginx
i want forward 80 port to domain

can use nginx or iptables or what ?
I searched, but everyone asks about forwarding Port to Port only
thank you

Comment: Please elaborate more on your requirement. Do you want to use port 80 for Nginx?

Comment: i want any one visit IP my centos 7 server forwarding it to domain i want

Answer (score 1):

You can edit Server tag in nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen      Server-IP:80;
    ...
}
```

This will route Server-IP:80 request to the Nginx server.